# Ubuntu - WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x8007041d (used to work now it doesn't)

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

For a University course I need Ubuntu installed on my Windows 10 computer. In class we installed the program and I was able to run it, but only after I enabled a Windows Feature - (Windows Subsystem for Linux). We had class again and the same error showed up again even after I had enabled the Windows Subsystem for Linux. I ran through the same process of again enabling the Windows feature and came to see that there were duplicate copies of each feature. [Windows Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2nlZ.png) I decided to just check the other box and see what would happen. The following errors resulted. [Error #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd1jm.png) and [Error #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6yM0.png). I decided to reboot my computer and see if that would do anything. I rebooted and then my computer got stuck on "Getting Windows Ready, Do not Turn off Your Computer". It sat there for approx. 1hr 30 min before finally getting through.

I'm backing up my desktop out of paranoia and just seems logical to do occasionally.

1. I will try to uninstall Ubuntu and reinstall it again to see if that does anything.
2. Pray that I don't have to do a clean install of Windows

I'm not sure why I would be getting duplicates of things on Windows Features, I think that's where my problem is stemming from.

Thanks for any advice or help

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me is to do a clean install of Widows. Fixed the issues completely.